# What is the new way to trim a String?

Tags: swift

Prior to being forced to switch to Swift 3.0 syntax, the following line worked just fine:

```
return urlString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(unwantedChars)
```

However, having updated to Swift 3.0, it now prevents me from building my app in Xcode, showing me the error message `Value of Type 'String' has no member 'StringByTrimmingCharactersInSet'`. What is the new syntax for this?

Comment: Please, always search on an error before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift3 inctroduced a lot of changes shortening api names and making them more 'swiftly'. Your code would look the following in swift3:

```
let st = s.trimmingCharacters(in: unwantedChars)
```